# Как к конкретному ключу в словаре

Tags: python, ооп

Например:

```
{'Делу время': (100, 5)}
```

Как я могу обратиться к ключу `"Делу время"`, без использования названия ключа (`d["Делу время"]`).
А также, как я могу обратиться к `1` значению ключа (`100`)? Также без его упоминания

Comment: Жесть какая-то. Если Вам это понадобилось, значит что-то Вы делаете не правильно

Answer (score 1):

Без использования ключа можно обратиться по индексу, если преобразовать словарь в список.

Элементами списка будут кортежи, к элементам которых тоже можно обращаться по индексу.

```
thisdict = {'Делу время': (100, 5)}
a = list(thisdict.items())
print(a[0])
print(a[0][1][0])

-->

('Делу время', (100, 5))
100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#             первое значение из словаря
#             ---------
    next(iter(next(iter(d.values()))))
#   ---------
#   первое значение из кортежа
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'Делу время': (100, 5)}
for el in d.items():
    print(el[0],el[1][0])


Делу время 100
```

Comment: Благодарю? А можно ли это сделать без цикла? Я буду использовать ключ как переменную

Comment: Какая задача?, решаете не ту проблему.